# Convert numerous date and time values into serial number

Tags: matlab

I need to convert date and time into a numerical value. for example:

```
>> num = datenum('2011-05-07 11:52:23')

num = 
   7.3463e+05
```

How would I write a script to do this for numerous values without inputting the date and time manually?

Comment: How are your date strings stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your date strings first in a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) (or a matrix, provided they are of fixed format), and feed it straight to [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html). For example:

```
C = {'2011-05-07 11:52:23'
     '2011-03-01 20:30:01'};
vals = datenum(C)
```